# Depth First Search Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm currently learning algorithms and was trying to adapt some code from Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick. Here's a link to the part of the code I'm having problems with: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/DirectedCycle.java.html.
For my code the dependencies are a Vertex class with a constructor that just takes a vertex number. I also have a DirectedEdge class, that has a fromVertex, a toVertex and a weight. Finally, I have an EdgeWeightedDigraph class that has a list of the vertices within the graph and a DirectedEdge adjacency list that holds a list of the edges adjacent to a particular vertex and a test class that just initializes the various instances variables with the data in addition to executing the DirectedCycle.java program. The code compiles and runs but returns a wrong cycle using the data supplied by the book (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/tinyDG.txt). The book specifies a Directed cycle: 3 5 4 3 but my code returns 3 2 3 instead. I noticed that the code runs fine until it encounters an already marked vertex and the onStack else-if code executes. For some reason the loop that contains the first call to dfs() iterates only once for index = 0 so after a marked vertex is encountered it does not retrace its steps and continue with the next vertex as it should with a depth first search. Not sure what I'm missing but any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need me to include the other code for the dependent classes listed above.

Here's my own code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class DirectedCycle {

    private boolean[] marked;
    private Vertex[] edgeTo;
    private Stack<Vertex> cycle;
    private boolean[] onStack;

    public DirectedCycle(EdgeWeightedDigraph graph) {
        onStack = new boolean[graph.getNumOfVertices()];
        edgeTo = new Vertex[graph.getNumOfVertices()];
        marked = new boolean[graph.getNumOfVertices()];

        for (int index = 0; index < graph.getVertices().size(); index++) {
            if (!marked[index] && cycle == null) {
                dfs(graph, graph.getVertex(index));

            }
        }

    }

    private void dfs(EdgeWeightedDigraph graph, Vertex vertex) {

        onStack[vertex.getVertexNumber()] = true;
        marked[vertex.getVertexNumber()] = true;

        for (DirectedEdge w : graph.adjacent(vertex)) {

            if (this.hasCycle()) {
                return;
            }
            else if (!marked[w.toVertex().getVertexNumber()]) {

                edgeTo[w.toVertex().getVertexNumber()] = vertex;
                dfs(graph, w.toVertex());

            }
            else if (onStack[w.toVertex().getVertexNumber()]) {

                cycle = new Stack<>();

                for (Vertex v = vertex; 
                         v.getVertexNumber() != w.toVertex().getVertexNumber(); 
                         v = edgeTo[v.getVertexNumber()]) {

                    cycle.push(v);
                }

                cycle.push(w.toVertex());
                cycle.push(vertex);
            }

        }

        onStack[vertex.getVertexNumber()] = false;

    }


    public boolean hasCycle() {
        return cycle != null;
    }

    public Iterable<Vertex> cycle() {
        return cycle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing wrong? `3 2 3` seems to be a correct answer. Maybe that is simply the first cycle that the algorithm discovers, after which `cycle != null` and all the other calls do `dfs()` get pruned. Please consider taking a look at the code that reads the input file. If it puts 2 before 5 in the adjacency list for 3, then that would explain it.

Comment: Oh... That makes sense actually. I'm thinking it may have to do with the fact that they used a  Bag to store the adjacency list whereas I used an ArrayList hence it was ordered...